# Snackbar covers coordinatorlayout's children

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a coordinator layout with children views that align themselves as I want, except when I show a `Snackbar`. Only the FAB (Floating Action Button) moves up as I expect it while the other views are hidden behind it.

I would rather want their height to reduced so that they can align themselves in top of the `Sanckbar.

Here's my `activity_layout.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/grid_view_item_image"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I know I can create my own `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` but I think I'm missing something and there so should be a simple way to do it, like it happens with the FAB.